# Laravel file from storage not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

Filesystem settings

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Upload file

```
 $path = $request->file('file-upload-photo-profile')->store('public/profile');

        $user->photo_profile_url =  Storage::url($path);
```

Patch to folder with file:

```
storage/app/public/profile
```

Example url:

Try get image:

```
   <img src="{{asset( $user->photo_profile_url)}}" >
```

Generated url:
http://sakura/storage/profile/aDtjR6z7Ih4fkmo7bdAqqyDXmhu2qE4pg3s5BBla.jpg

But I got  404 for this image.
In server settings root dirrectory

```
public
```

How do I get a link to an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the [symlink](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) to the storage folder in your `app/public` directory?

Like so: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Yes. The [D:\openServer535\OSPanel\domains\sakura\sakura\public\storage] link already exists.
The links have been created.